# Sql convert loop of updates in a single update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this procedure in my postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_meals(
    integer,
    integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN $1..$2 LOOP
        UPDATE meals
        SET protein = query.protein,
            carbs = query.carbs,
            fat = query.fat,

        FROM (
            SELECT meals.id as meal_id, 
                sum(ingredients.protein) as protein, 
                sum(ingredients.carbs) as carbs, 
                sum(ingredients.fat) as fat,
            FROM meals
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN mixers ON meals.id = mixers.meal_id 
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN ingredients ON mixers.ingredient_id = ingredients.id
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN recipes ON mixers.recipe_id = recipes.id
            WHERE meals.id = i
            GROUP BY meals.id
        ) AS query
        WHERE id = i;
    END LOOP;
RETURN TRUE;
END;    
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION update_meals(integer, integer)
  OWNER TO root;
```

I would know if I can do this update in only one update and if is **more efficent** in terms of time comsumption. 
Taking into account that the query had been reduced for better understanding, the important point here is if I can get the 'current row' id on subquery, that means, **if can I remove de FOR**

Comment: `WHERE id between $1 and $2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and what do you do with subquery? Erase the where line of subquery produce a very huge query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single statement and push the condition into the derived table and use a join condition on the target table:

```
UPDATE meals
  SET protein = query.protein,
      carbs = query.carbs,
      fat = query.fat,
FROM (
    SELECT meals.id as meal_id, 
        sum(ingredients.protein) as protein, 
        sum(ingredients.carbs) as carbs, 
        sum(ingredients.fat) as fat,
    FROM meals
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN mixers ON meals.id = mixers.meal_id 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN ingredients ON mixers.ingredient_id = ingredients.id
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN recipes ON mixers.recipe_id = recipes.id
    WHERE meals.id between $1 and $2 ---<< here
    GROUP BY meals.id
) AS query
WHERE meals.id = query.meal_id --<< here;
```

Comment: Are you sure that this query is more efficient than previous one?

Comment: @ppascualv: well, you asked to turn the loop into a single statement. Run it and test for yourself. But in almost all cases a single statement is more efficient then many statements

Comment: Actually I ask for the two things (there are in bold), thank you anyway I will test your answer.